# R error.bars get all x-axis labels

Tags: r

I am trying to plot means with standard deviations using the error.bars and it works quite good.
I know I could also use the ggplot approach but I could not implement that for my data...

So far so good, the problem that I ran into now, is that not all variables on the x-axis are printed, in fact only every second or so.

In boxplot, I could fix this with the command, `names, las=2`. Is there something similar for the error.bars function? I could not find anything in the manual.

Here's the code I am using:

```
psych:::error.bars(orderedcols,sd=TRUE,add=TRUE,arrow.len=0.05,bars=TRUE, xlab="Adjectives", ylab="Mean Intensity", main="Mean Intensities and Standard Deviations")
```

**EDIT:**

> dput(orderedcols)
>   structure(list(brilliant = c(50, 82, 80, 12, 80, 80, 85, 72, 
>   80, 85, 65, 100, 90, 97, 85, 95, 100, 100), ingenious = c(75, 
>   70, 50, 79, 85, 80, 100, 50, 95, 90, 50, 100, 100, 1, 80, 83, 
>   83, 100), intelligent = c(40, 70, 45, 87, 75, 60, 80, 42, 86, 
>   80, 29, 100, 50, 45, 61, 77, 40, 90), bright = c(20, 60, 40, 
>   58, 65, 50, 75, 40, 77, 55, 50, 58, 50, 56, 76, 83, 30, 75), 
>       smart = c(30, 62, 25, 47, 45, 50, 50, 32, 54, 75, 27, 81, 
>       70, 69, 40, 85, 29, 80), brainy = c(60, 66, 20, 52, 70, 60, 
>       50, 20, 66, 35, 31, -9, -10, 44, 78, 91, 50, 70), foolish = c(-15, 
>       -35, -20, -44, -30, -10, -20, -10, -32, -25, -27, -23, -10, 
>       -15, -25, 43, -36, -10), daft = c(-10, -60, -30, -14, -20, 
>       -10, -77, 0, -90, -20, -36, -61, 10, 0, -33, -100, -21, -50
>       ), dim = c(-35, -62, -20, 8, -80, -30, -35, -24, -60, -35, 
>       -34, -9, -100, -34, -83, -71, -27, -20), dumb = c(-25, -50, 
>       -60, -37, -40, -30, -25, -29, -76, -75, -78, -37, 0, -30, 
>       -39, -91, -38, -10), mindless = c(-50, -55, -60, -12, -30, 
>       -50, -25, 0, -62, -50, -100, -100, 0, -6, -39, -52, -59, 
>       -25), inane = c(-20, -80, -30, -6, -35, -30, -90, -25, -50, 
>       -50, -38, -100, -75, -25, -12, -100, -22, -10), stupid = c(-25, 
>       -80, -30, -75, -50, -40, -80, -28, -37, -75, -41, -50, -11, 
>       -100, -51, -91, -36, -15), dimwitted = c(-50, -77, -20, -59, 
>       -40, -60, -66, -77, -45, -25, -32, -77, -100, -46, -74, -89, 
>       -39, -30), idiotic = c(-60, -91, -50, -26, -60, -50, -83, 
>       -41, -58, -80, 30, -86, -100, -46, -91, -89, -60, -40), moronic = c(-90, 
>       -87, -40, -19, -65, -60, -90, -85, -78, -75, -59, -100, -80, 
>       -22, -71, -95, -65, -15), brainless = c(-75, -85, -80, -55, 
>       -20, -100, -90, -35, -85, -90, -31, -100, -90, -73, -31, 
>       -63, -100, -95), imbecilic = c(-100, -95, -75, 31, -50, -75, 
>       -90, -100, -72, -85, -63, -98, -100, -33, -92, -90, -74, 
>       -100)), .Names = c("brilliant", "ingenious", "intelligent", 
>   "bright", "smart", "brainy", "foolish", "daft", "dim", "dumb", 
>   "mindless", "inane", "stupid", "dimwitted", "idiotic", "moronic", 
>   "brainless", "imbecilic"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(2L, 
>   4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
>   19L, 20L, 21L))
>       11        72        50          42     40    32     20     -10    0  -24  -29        0   -25    -28       -77     -41     -85       -35      -100
>       12        80        95          86     77    54     66     -32  -90  -60  -76      -62   -50    -37       -45     -58     -78       -85       -72
>       13        85        90          80     55    75     35     -25  -20  -35  -75      -50   -50    -75       -25     -80     -75       -90       -85
>       14        65        50          29     50    27     31     -27  -36  -34  -78     -100   -38    -41       -32      30     -59       -31       -63
>       15       100       100         100     58    81     -9     -23  -61   -9  -37     -100  -100    -50       -77     -86    -100      -100       -98
>       16        90       100          50     50    70    -10     -10   10 -100    0        0   -75    -11      -100    -100     -80       -90      -100
>       17        97         1          45     56    69     44     -15    0  -34  -30       -6   -25   -100       -46     -46     -22       -73       -33
>       18        85        80          61     76    40     78     -25  -33  -83  -39      -39   -12    -51       -74     -91     -71       -31       -92
>       19        95        83          77     83    85     91      43 -100  -71  -91      -52  -100    -91       -89     -89     -95       -63       -90
>       20       100        83          40     30    29     50     -36  -21  -27  -38      -59   -22    -36       -39     -60     -65      -100       -74
>       21       100       100          90     75    80     70     -10  -50  -20  -10      -25   -10    -15       -30     -40     -15       -95      -100

P.S. can't add a photo, have too little reputation..

Comment: *<sigh>* it's really pretty difficult to comment without a peep at the data you are using and the rest of the code you are using to plot.

Comment: sorry, I'll add the dataframe that I am using right now

Comment: Great! If you can paste the output from running the R console command `dput( mydataframe )` that will allow people to copy and paste it straight back into their R session to recreate your data. You can't copy/paste that

Comment: sorry about that, like that?

Comment: Exactly! :-) Now that people can recreate your data easily I am sure you will find more help forthcoming.

Comment: The issue is simply that you're trying to plot more bars than you have room for. It looks like `error.bars` hard codes a call to `axis` to draw the axis labels, so you're not going to be able to adjust how they are drawn without modifying the code itself (which isn't that hard in this case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually pretty easy, I think: all you have to do is set the `las` graphical parameter before you run the `error.bars` command:

```
par(las=2)
error.bars(orderedcols,sd=TRUE,add=TRUE,arrow.len=0.05,bars=TRUE,
           xlab="Adjectives", ylab="Mean Intensity",
           main="Mean Intensities and Standard Deviations")
```

A `ggplot2` solution (you could rotate the labels for this one too -- search on StackOverflow for how to do it -- but I chose to rotate the whole plot instead)

```
library("reshape2")
library("ggplot2")
theme_set(theme_bw())
ggplot(melt(orderedcols),aes(x=variable,y=value))+
    stat_summary(geom="bar",fun.y=mean,position="identity",fill="gray")+
    stat_summary(geom="errorbar",width=0.2,
                 fun.data=function(x) { data.frame(y=mean(x), 
                     ymin=mean(x)-sd(x),ymax=mean(x)+sd(x)) })+
    coord_flip()
```

Comment: <facepalm!> Totally forgot about setting `las` outside of the function first.

Comment: thanks, looks perfect to me! i did not no about the par function and that I could set the las outside the error.bars function even though that particular parameter is not included in it.